# perldoc shows "Can't find any loadable formatter class in Pod" error?

Tags: perl, perldoc

I am running this:

```
$ perldoc Bio::EnsEMBL::Slice

Can't find any loadable formatter class in Pod::Perldoc::Toman Pod::Perldoc::Toman Pod::Perldoc::ToMan Pod::Perldoc::ToMAN Pod::Simple::man Pod::Simple::man Pod::Simple::Man Pod::Simple::MAN Pod::man Pod::man Pod::Man Pod::MAN Pod::Perldoc::Totext Pod::Perldoc::Totext Pod::Perldoc::ToText Pod::Perldoc::ToTEXT Pod::Simple::text Pod::Simple::text Pod::Simple::Text Pod::Simple::TEXT Pod::text Pod::text Pod::Text Pod::TEXT Pod::Perldoc::ToPod?!
Aborting
 at /usr/bin/perldoc line 10.
```

and get this above error. I have installed the ensembl properly but perldoc is showing error. Can you give your suggestions in resolving this issue? Thanks!

Comment: perldoc needs to load one of the mentioned modules in order to produce formatted output, and none can be found. What OS environment are you using? It sound more like an OS package management question than a Perl question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am using ubuntu 14.04. Any suggestion on how this can be resolved?

Comment: Your Perl installation is broken. Does Ubuntu have packages called `perl` and/or `perl-doc`? I'd try to reinstall those.

Answer (score 2):

perldoc drops privileges to nobody or equivalent when run as root. If the current directory  is not readable as that user, you will get this error, tested on v5.30.3.